# Error 405 - Method Not Allowed when accessing WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2

I am setting up WSO2 EMM as a test and followed the guide on how to install the product.  I am able to access the WSO2 ESB with no problem but not the EMM.  Can you please help?  Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by access?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a browser caching issue.Can you try clearing your browser cache and try again. Make sure you accessing the following URL.

https://localhost:9443/carbon

Answer (score 0):

Try below URL for EMM. You cannot access it from the carbon console

https://localhost:9443/emm